# Differential Equation for brownian bridge?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, partial-differential-equations, soft-question

For the brownian motion, we know that probability density of the particle's position at time $ t $, $ \rho(x,t) $ satisfies the diffusion equation pde: $ \partial_t \rho = d \; \partial_x^2 \rho $. Is there some similar statement for the brownian bridge, something of the form: the probability density of the particle's position $\rho $ satisfies $ L \rho = 0 $ for some differential operator $L $ with the boundary conditions $ \rho(x,0) = \rho(x,1) = \delta(x) $?

Comment: We can write a Brownian bridge as a stochastic integral wrt a standard Brownian motion, and thus there is an SDE, driven by a standard Brownian motion, which the Brownian bridge satisfies. The Feynmann-Kac theorem says there is a differential operator $L$ specified by the SDE such that if the Brownian bridge has a density wrt Lebesgue measure, $p(x,t)$, then $p$ satisfies the equation $\partial_t p = Lp$. So the answer (I believe) is yes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not too good with SDE, since my interest in this is from an entirely different area, so I'll try to digest your answer.